# Decoding instruction using opcode and function bits

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, decoder, machine-instruction

I am trying to design a pipelined-cpu-simulator. As a part of that i need to design a control unit.

What i am expecting the control unit to do is - to set the values of following flags:

```
reg_write (=1 if the instruction writes a value to some register, =0 otherwise)
mem_read (=1 if the instruction reads a value from memory, =0 otherwise)
mem_write (=1 if the instruction writes a value to memory, =0 otherwise)
jump (=1 if the instruction is a jump instruction, =0 otherwise)
etc.
```

I need to set these values as a function of the opcode and function bits of the instruction. How can i do that?

Comment: What is the Instruction Set Architecture, ARM, x86, MIPS, something else?

Comment: @Danny: The architecture is MIPS